# Format date with time in bind variable APX

Tags: asp.net

I have in my ASPX this bind variable

```
Text='<%# Bind("PLANSTART","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM}") %>'
```

The imput date is this one 28.09.12 13:45 and I want to display "September 28, 2012 13:45" but I optain this: "September 28, 2012 13:00 "

thanks

Comment: quite strange result as according to format you posted you should get `28/09/2012 13:09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, `MM` to `mm`

```
Text='<%# Bind("PLANSTART","{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}") %>'
```